# C++ alternative to perror()

Tags: c++, c, error-handling, errno, cross-language

I know we can use

```
perror()
```

in C to print errors. I was just wondering if there is a C++ alternative to this, or whether I have to include this (and therefore stdio.h) in my program. I am trying to avoid as many C functions as possible.

Comment: For those who don't know, but immediately just say "use `cerr`", the usefulness of `perror()` is that it actually interprets the `errno` and displays it accordingly. I assume he wants the interpretation just as much as the console output...

Comment: Could you please try to explain how you want to print errors? The C-functions are included in C++ as well, there's nothing wrong with using them.

Comment: Simon, one of the the reasons to avoid C-like printing functions in C++ programs is that some care (flushing) is needed when mixing e.g. `printf` and `cout`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708482

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
std::cerr << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
```

That still ends up calling `strerror`, so you're really just substituting one C function for another. OTOH, it does let you write via streams, instead of mixing C and C++ output, which is generally a good thing. At least AFAIK, C++ doesn't add anything to the library to act as a substitute for `strerror` (other than generating an `std::string`, I'm not sure what it would change from `strerror` anyway).

Comment: A C++ version of `strerror` which would return a `std::string` would presumably also be thread-safe, which would be a nice improvement.

Comment: @Tyler: Well, that's certainly possible, and would be a handy improvement. OTOH, getting thread safety out of anything that uses `errno` almost unavoidably uses thread local storage anyway (i.e., about the same as it takes to make `strerror` thread safe).

Comment: @Jerry I'm not sure about other threading frameworks, but POSIX threads guarantee that `errno` is thread-local automatically. The problem with `strerror` is that it returns a pointer to a static buffer that is not thread-local.

Comment: @Tyler: My point was that to make `errno` work, you need to have and use TLS anyway, and once you're using it, you might as well use it for `strerror`'s buffer too.

Comment: @Tyler McHenry: Having an error-message-creation-function that creates a std::string would be very inappropriate. How would that function work if it would try to report "out of memory"? I would say that an error-function that takes a char* buffer with a given size would be the most appropriate. It's also "thread-safe".

Comment: @Simon And there exists such a thing (`perror_r`), although you do have a point about out-of-memory errors.

Comment: Thanks all. Really helpful! The fact that I can stream it makes me like it more. I don't like mixing C & C++ if I can help it. The sterror issue (non-local static buffers) is something I'll have to check, although we should be using POSIX threads, so...

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `boost::system_error::error_code` class.

```
#include <boost/system/system_error.hpp>

#include <cerrno>
#include <iostream>

void
PrintError(
        const std::string& message,
        int error
        )
{
    std::cerr << message << ": " <<
            boost::system::error_code(
                error,
                boost::system::get_system_category()
                ).message()
            << std::endl;
}

int
main()
{
    PrintError( "something went wrong!", EINVAL );
    return 0;
}
```

it's a tad verbose, and somewhat overkill if you aren't already using the boost_system library.

Comment: Wouldn't that be pretty bad if you happen to do PrintError("We ran out of memory!", EINVAL); when you discover that you failed to do a memory-allocation?

Comment: Can't actually use the boost library. This has to be as 'plain' (for lack of a better term) as possible. Trying not to include any 3rd party stuff. Thanks though!

Answer (score 2):

With C++11, we have the <system_error> header, so you should be able to use:

```
std::error_code{errno, std::generic_category()}.message();
```

Example program:

```
#include <system_error>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << std::error_code{errno, std::generic_category()}.message() << '\n';
}
```

This [prints](https://godbolt.org/z/cdMnTGen5) `Success`.

See also:

- [How to convert errno to exception using <system_error>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12171377/1593077)
- [<system_error> categories and standard/system error codes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28746372/1593077) 
  (regarding whether to use `generic_category` or `system_category`)