# What is the C++ stream equivalent to perror?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ alternative to perror()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320898/c-alternative-to-perror)

I can't find the stream equivalent to `perror`. Is there such a thing? I like the fact that I can call:

```
perror("Error");
```

And it will fill in what `errno` is. Can I do this with streams?

Comment: @Erik: Yes!... I saw that function before, I just couldn't come up with it again. Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To print an error message:

```
str << strerror(errno);
```

If you're talking about the streams error state - no you can't get an automatic meaningful error message for that.

Answer (score 5):

Since `perror` writes to *stderr*, any equivalent in C++ has to do exactly the same. That is, it is not sufficient to write `strerror(errno)` to a stream. The stream itself should (I'd say must) be a stream to *standard error*.

The following code snippet/pseudo code should give you an idea:

```
// depending on your compiler, this is all you need to include
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

 ... somewhere in your code...

std::cerr << "Error: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
```