# How to convert errno to exception using <system_error>

Tags: c++, exception, c++11

I read a thoughtful [series of blog posts](http://blog.think-async.com/2010/04/system-error-support-in-c0x-part-1.html) about the new `<system_error>` header in C++11.  It says that the header defines an `error_code` class that represents a specific error value returned by an operation (such as a system call).  It says that the header defines a `system_error` class, which is an exception class (inherits from `runtime_exception`) and is used to wrap `error_codes`s.

What I want to know is how to actually convert a system error from `errno` into a `system_error` so I can throw it.  For example, the POSIX `open` function reports errors by returning -1 and setting `errno`, so if I want to throw an exception how should I complete the code below?

```
void x()
{
    fd = open("foo", O_RDWR);
    if (fd == -1)
    {
        throw /* need some code here to make a std::system_error from errno */;
    }
}
```

I randomly tried:

```
errno = ENOENT;
throw std::system_error();
```

but the resulting exception returns no information when `what()` is called.

I know I could do `throw errno;` but I want to do it the right way, using the new `<system_error>` header.

There is a constructor for `system_error` that takes a single `error_code` as its argument, so if I can just convert `errno` to `error_code` then the rest should be obvious.

This seems like a really basic thing, so I don't know why I can't find a good tutorial on it.

I am using gcc 4.4.5 on an ARM processor, if that matters.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You are on the right track, just pass the error code and a [`std::generic_category`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/generic_category) object to the `std::system_error` [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/system_error/system_error) and it should work.

Example:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <system_error>

int main()
{
    try
    {
        throw std::system_error(EFAULT, std::generic_category());
    }
    catch (std::system_error& error)
    {
        std::cout << "Error: " << error.code() << " - " << error.what() << '\n';
        assert(error.code() == std::errc::bad_address);
    }
}
```

Output from the above program on my system is

```
Error: generic:14 - Bad address
```

Comment: Cool, that works!  For some reason, on my system that exact same code just outputs "Error: system:14 - " but I'm probably not using the latest version of libstdc++ or something.

Comment: For anyone else with the same problem, I found that `error.what()` returns an empty string but `error.code().message()` returns a nice string.

Comment: Can't you just throw `std::system_error(EFAULT, std::system_category());`

Comment: @Cubbi You're right, didn't think of that. Updated answer to reflect that.

Comment: This is great, but what if you want to check the error code against one of the generic members of the `errc` enum? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46370615/how-do-i-use-the-generic-error-codes-enum-with-system-category-error-codes-from

Comment: To wrap a POSIX `errno` codes, use the [std::generic_category](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/generic_category). [std::system_category](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/system_category) is meant to be used for errors reported by the operating system.

Comment: @IInspectable On a POSIX system I would argue that those error codes *are* from the operating system. Sure some errors could come from utility functions or the C library functions, but they could also come from *system calls* like `write` and `socket`.

Comment: To my knowledge, all systems that implement POSIX also provide extensions. Not using the correct error category is very likely to produce bugs down the road, even if most of the time it doesn't matter.

Comment: Yet another C++ blunder... What a messy interface for such a common task!

Answer (score 13):

To add to the excellent accepted answer, you can enrich the error message with some contextual information in the 3rd argument, e.g. the failing file name:

```
std::string file_name = "bad_file_name.txt";
fd = open(file_name, O_RDWR);
if (fd < 0) {
    throw std::system_error(errno, std::generic_category(), file_name);
}
```

Then when caught, `e.what()` will return, for example:

```
bad_file_name.txt: file not found
```