# How to check if a file exists (regardless of its file type)?

Tags: c++, linux

Edit: The problem wasn't with my c++. The problem was with how I was calling the shared library in GameMaker Studio, which was why it wasn't working.

I'm trying to detect whether a file exists, and I've tried many methods over the internet and none of them seem to work. Here's an example:

```
double file_exists(char *filename)
{
    std::ifstream infile(filename);
    return infile.good();
}
```

I assume it will only work with text files. for example, this won't work:

```
file_exists("/usr/bin/gedit");
```

...because that is a Linux executable.

I want a means to check whether a file exists regardless of its file type.

On Windows, this can easily be achieved like so:

```
double file_exists(char* filename)
{
    DWORD fileAtt = GetFileAttributesA(filename);
    if(fileAtt == INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES)
        throw GetLastError();

    return (bool)((fileAtt&FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) == 0);
}
```

But I'm on Linux and I need an equivalent of the above snippet that will work on Linux.

Comment: [`stat`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) or [`access`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/access.2.html) are two POSIX functions that could be used. Or use [Boost filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) or the upcoming [standard filesystem library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem).

Comment: Also, when opening a file using C++ streams the system doesn't care about its "filetype". A file is a file is a file... A "text" file is just a way of interpreting the contents by the application, the stream itself doesn't really care about the contents.

Comment: Your example works fine for `"/usr/bin/gedit"`

Comment: "I assume it will" well now the next logical step would be to verify your assumption.

Comment: BTW, why is your function returning `double` instead of `bool`?

Comment: I said "I assume" because I was trying to rationalize why it wasn't working, which I did verify that it wasn't working, otherwise I never would've posted this question. I've also tried stat and access before I posted this question and neither of them returned true even though gedit clearly exists on my machine. I'm making it return a double because this is a GameMaker Studio extension. GameMaker can only read doubles and chars. It won't recognize the function value if it returns a bool.

Answer (score 2):

In Linux you have the `stat()` system call:

```
struct stat st;
int res = stat(filename, &st);
bool exists = res == 0;
```

If you want more finesse, you can check the `errno` if `res` is non-zero:

```
if (res == 0)
    return true;
if (errno == ENOENT)
    return false;
throw errno; //you're throwing an int, aren't you?
```

Also, as a bonus, if you want to know if it is a directory or a normal file or a fifo or a socket or a device... you can check the contents of `st.st_mode`.

Comment: Instead of throwing `errno` directly I suggest you use [`std::system_error`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/system_error) (see e.g. [this old answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12171615/440558) for an example).

Comment: I usually throw `std::runtime_error(std::strerror(errno));` to get a useful message

Comment: All that is nice. I was throwing `errno` just because the OP is throwing `GetLastError()` directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on `Linux` then `GCC` implements the *filesystem* Technical Specification, soon to be included in `C++17`.

You can use [std::filesystem::exists](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/exists).

```
#include <experimental/filesystem>

namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;

int main()
{
    if(fs::exists("/usr/bin/gedit"))
    {
        ...
        // use file here
    }
}
```