# How do I use the generic error codes enum with system_category error codes from <system_error>?

Tags: c++, c++11, exception

I have this code (very similar to [what is suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12171615)) that throws an exception:

```
int accept4(int sockfd, sockaddr *addr, socklen_t *addrlen, int flags)
{
   const int fd = ::accept4(sockfd, addr, addrlen, flags);
   if (fd < 0)
   {
       const auto tmp = errno;
       throw ::std::system_error(tmp, ::std::system_category(), "accept4(2)");
   }
   else
   {
      return fd;
   }
}
```

And this code for testing for a particular exception reason:

```
catch (const ::std::system_error &e)
{
   static const auto block_err = ::std::system_error(EWOULDBLOCK,
                                                     ::std::system_category());

   const auto ecode = e.code(); 

   // EWOULBLOCK is fine, everything else, re-throw it.
   if (block_err.code() != ecode)
   {
      throw;
   }
}
```

This seems kind of needlessly verbose and not quite the right way to do things. There's this whole idea of generic errors and a whole enum (see [`::std::errc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/errc)) full of them along with some kind of system that's supposed to convert between system specific error codes and these generic errors.

I want to use the generic error codes and categories, and I can't seem to get them to work. How do I make that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On an implementation of sufficiently high quality<sup>*</sup>, it suffices to do

```
if (e.code() != std::errc::operation_would_block)
    throw;
```

If not, you are stuck with

```
if (e.code() != std::error_code(EWOULDBLOCK, std::system_category()))
    throw;
```

There's certainly no need to construct another `system_error` just for the error code inside.

---

<sup>*</sup> It needs to implement `system_category()`'s `default_error_condition` to appropriately map the error to `generic_category()`.