# How to extract error from a system call?

Tags: c, unix, system-calls

For example in man page it says:

```
The mmap() function shall fail if:

EACCES
The fildes argument is not open for read, regardless of the protection specified,        
fildes is not open for write and PROT_WRITE was specified for a MAP_SHARED type 
mapping.
```

There are bunch of other cases. I am assuming there is a way to check which error has occurred however a hour of search yielded nothing. How do you check if that particular error has occured?

Comment: Probably using errno.h if that is what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

That error value will be saved in the global variable [`errno`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/errno.3.html).  You can get a human readable string from [`perror(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/perror.3.html).

Comment: `strerror` is usually preferable to `perror` unless you just want to write an error message to `stderr` and exit..

Comment: you mean doing if(errno == EACCES)? I tried that, it did not work.Even though I set the access permission different.

Comment: By the way, not that any further calls to the standard library after `mmap` fails, even successful calls, could clobber the contents of `errno`. Thus, you probably want to save it in a local variable first thing in the block that runs when `mmap` returns `MAP_FAILED`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this if you are using C++

```
std::cerr << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
```

More detailed information can be found here:

[C++ alternative to perror()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320898/c-alternative-to-perror)

Comment: The question is tagged C, not C++.