# perror and std::cerr use

Tags: c++

Can anyone please tell me what are the usage differences between `std::cerr` and `perror`

```
void perror ( const char * str );
```

I wonder which one is preferable in C++ applications and why it's preferable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ alternative to perror()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320898/c-alternative-to-perror)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question basically boils down to iostream vs stdio. A similar question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872543/printf-vs-cout-in-c).

If you're working in C++ cerr is definitely preferable to perror unless you want to do something very specific. The only real difference is that cerr is virtually the same as

```
fprintf(stderr, const char*, arg1, ...);
```

while perror will also load and display the appropriate error message depending on errno. Also you can't display variables with perror so you can't do

```
perror("Something went wrong, i: %d", i);
```

unless you preprocess your error message.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/perror/

`perror` and `cerr` are different things. `cerr` - is object of `std::ostream` class connected with `stderr`. And `perror` prints `errno` and your string in `stderr`.