# Why does <iostream> operator<< pick the apparently wrong overload?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, iostream

Consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class X {
public:
    operator const wchar_t* () const { return L"Hello"; }
};

void f(const void *) {
    wcout << L"f(const void*)\n";
}

void f(const wchar_t*) {
    wcout << L"f(const wchar_t*)\n";
}

int main() {
    X x;
    f(x);

    wcout << x;
}
```

The output is (compiled with the VS2015 C++ compiler):

> ```
> f(const wchar_t*)
> 00118B30
> ```

So it seems that the compiler selects the *expected* `const wchar_t*` overload for `f` (as there's an implicit conversion from `X` to `const wchar_t*`).

However, it seems that `wcout << x` picks the `const void*` overload, instead of the `const wchar_t*` one (printing an address, instead of a `wchar_t` string).

Why is this?

**P.S.** I know that the proper way of printing `X` is to implement an overload of `operator<<` like `wostream& operator<<(wostream& , const X&)`, but that is *not* the point of the question.

Comment: This might not be it, but your program has [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947949/mixing-cout-and-wcout-in-same-program). You can't mix and match `std::cout` and `std::wcout`.

Comment: @Rakete1111: That's not the point. Feel free to use wcout instead of cout to track the selected overloads of f :)

Comment: It might not be the point but asking why a program with undefined behavior behaves a certain way doesn't make any sense, even if in your case it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @KingThrushbeard: No, printing an object does not yield its address, unless you write a function which does that.

Comment: For those complaining about mixing wcout and cout, I changed the code to use wcout instead of cout in the trace messages inside f overloads. Same output.

Comment: Note that the operator which prints `const void*` is a member function, and the one which prints `const wchar_t*` is a non-member function. I'm not familiar enough with the lookup rules to cite why that should matter, but I'm pretty sure it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because when deducing template arguments the conversion functions are not considered:

```
// Non-template member function.
basic_ostream& basic_ostream::operator<<( const void* value );

// Template non-member function.
template< class CharT, class Traits >
basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& operator<<( basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& os, 
                                         const CharT* s );
```

The second declaration does not consider the conversion `operator const wchar_t* () const`.

I cannot find the standard quote, [cppreference Template argument deduction, Implicit conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Implicit_conversions) says:

> Type deduction does not consider implicit conversions (other than type adjustments listed above): that's the job for overload resolution, which happens later.

Comment: If you remove the non-template it will not even compile, because implicit conversion doesn't happen for template argument deduction. :)