# A minimum cross-platform piece of code to print this right?

Tags: c++, unicode, cout

Consider the following example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "abc" << std::endl;
    std::wcout << L"abc" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "абв" << std::endl;
    std::wcout << L"абв" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

On Linux its output goes like this:

```
abc
abc
абв
012
```

On Windows it's like this (note the absence of the last line):

```
abc
abc
рст
```

What (minimum) changes do I need to make to print "абв" right on both platforms?

ETA: Please note that this question is not about mixing different streams (removing either `cout` or `wcout` fixes nothing), nor is it about source file encoding (reading the strings instead of hardcoding them does not help either).

Comment: You first need to establish that the source code, given the non-ASCII string literal, gives the same character sequence in both environments.

Comment: You don't: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947949/mixing-cout-and-wcout-in-same-program

Comment: @NathanOliver: Would you say this is a duplicate of that question?

Comment: you can put the string to a file and read from it... I think the problem is the cpp files must be in ASCII formats...

Comment: @elvis.dukaj Why would you think that?  (They don't)

Comment: @FredLarson I didn't want to hammer it if others didn't agree but if you think It fits I'll hammer it.

Comment: @UKMonkey give a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331690/using-unicode-in-c-source-code

Comment: @NathanOliver: I feel the same way. I support hammering it.

Comment: You can write your own custom `std::cout/std::in` to handle UTF8 in Windows. Also use `std::experimental::filesystem` to read/write files in UTF8. Linux already supports UTF8 (`u8"абв"`) This should give reasonable compatibility between Linux and Windows.