# HEX value to wchar_t character (UTF-8) conversion

Tags: c++, linux, c++14

I am holding hex values in unsigned integers `size_t` and would like to convert them into `wchar_t` to hold in a data-structure and, optionally print to `std::cout` as it's UTF-8 symbol/character when valid.

I've tried casting without much success: `size_t h = 0x262E;` prints `9774` when doing a cast to `wchar_t` for example.

Some minimal code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
   std::setlocale( LC_ALL, "" );
   auto v = std::vector<size_t>( 3, 0x262E ); // 3x peace symbols
   v.at( 1 ) += 0x10; // now a moon symbol

   for( auto &el : v )
       std::cout << el << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

Output: `9774 9790 9774`
What I want: `☮ ☾ ☮`

I can print the symbols using `printf( "%lc ", (wchar_t) el );`. Is there a better "modern" C++ solution to this?

I need to be able to print anything in the range of `0000-27BF` UTF-8 on linux **only**.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/402918/2502409

Comment: Use `std::wcout` for printing instead of `std::cout`. 9774 is the decimal value of 0x262E btw.

Comment: What are the hex values? Unicode code points are in the range `0` to `0x10FFFF`. UTF8 uses variable length encoding, each code point is represented by 1, 2, 3, or 4 bytes, the conversion is not trivial, casting won't work between different encodings. Show real example of your input.

Comment: I think you need to show your code because there are a lot of moving parts. I believe everything below 128 is its ASCII code in Unicode/UCS-16/UCS-32, etc. Just assign the ASCII code for the character. Also, UTF-8 uses 8-bit `char`'s, not `wchar_t`'s. Finally, `wchar_t` is usually printed as an `unsigned short` or `unsigned int` (depending on the platform), and not a character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `std::wcout` with `wchar_t` cast to print the wide characters instead of `std::cout`.

Here's your corrected functional code ([live example](https://ideone.com/nPoRRH)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
   std::setlocale( LC_ALL, "" );
   auto v = std::vector<size_t>( 3, 0x262E ); // 3x peace symbols
   v.at( 1 ) += 0x10; // now a moon symbol

   for( auto &el : v )
       std::wcout << (wchar_t) el << " "; // <--- Corrected statement

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
☮ ☾ ☮
```

---

In case you have hex string numbers, you can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10156436/7670262) solution.

Comment: Thanks @Azeem, that works. For future readers there is a side note: ````std::cout```` and ````std::wcout```` don't mix and unexpected stuff will come out [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947949/mixing-cout-and-wcout-in-same-program).