# Correct way to print wide strings to terminals with different encodings

Tags: c++, character-encoding, cout, widechar

Below I will try to print string `XЯ` (latin "ex", cyrillic "ya", and Phoenician "teth") to terminals with various encodings, namely utf8, cp1251 and C (POSIX). I expect to see `XЯ` in utf8 terminal, `XЯ?` in cp1251 terminal, and `X??` in C (POSIX) terminal. Question marks are because C++ output library replaces characters which it cannot represent with `?`. This is correct and expected behavior.

(1) My first naive attempt was to just print wide character string to wcout:

```
wchar_t str[] = L"\U00000058\U0000042f\U00010908";
std::wcout << str << std::endl;
// utf8 terminal output: X??
// cp1251: X??
// C: X??
```

In all terminals, it printed correctly only the first, ascii7, character. Other characters were replaced with '?' marks. It turned out that this happened because during program startup, LC_ALL is [set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/setlocale) to C.

(2) Second attempt was to manually call `std::setlocale()` with utf8 encoding:

```
wchar_t str[] = L"\U00000058\U0000042f\U00010908";
std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");
std::wcout << str << std::endl;
// utf8: XЯ
// cp1251: XРЇрђ¤€
// C: XÐ¯ð¤
```

Obviously, this worked correctly in utf8 terminal, but resulted in garbage in other two terminals.

(3) Third attempt was to parse `$LANG` environment variable for actual encoding used by terminal (and hope that all pieces of the terminal [use the same encoding](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112216/which-terminal-encodings-are-default-on-linux-and-which-are-most-common)):

```
const char* lang = std::getenv("LANG");
if (!lang) {
  std::cerr << "Couldn't get LANG" << std::endl;
  exit(1);
}

wchar_t str[] = L"\U00000058\U0000042f\U00010908";
std::setlocale(LC_ALL, lang);
std::wcout << str << std::endl;
// utf8: XЯ
// cp1251: XЯ?
// C: X??
```

Now the output in all three terminals was as I expected. However, [mixing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947949/mixing-cout-and-wcout-in-same-program) `std::cout` and `std::wcout` is a bad idea, and `std::cout` is definitely used by some third-party libraries used in my program. This makes `std::wcout` unusable.

(4) So, fourth attempt (or, actually, idea) was to detect terminal encoding from `$LANG`, use `codevct()` to convert `wchar_t[]` string into terminal encoding and print it with ordinary `std::cout.write()`. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a way to explicitly set target encoding for `codevct()`.

(5) Fifth, and so far, the best, attempt was to use `iconv()` manually:

```
// get $LANG env var
const char* lang = std::getenv("LANG");
if (!lang) {
  std::cerr << "Couldn't get $LANG" << std::endl;
  exit(1);
}

// find out encoding from $LANG, e.g. "utf8", "cp1251", etc
std::string enc(lang);
size_t pos = enc.rfind('.');
if (pos != std::string::npos) {
  enc = enc.substr(pos + 1);
}
if (enc == "C" || enc == "POSIX") {
  enc = "iso8859-1";
}

// convert wchar_t[] string into terminal encoding
wchar_t str[] = L"\U00000058\U0000042f\U00010908";
iconv_t handler = iconv_open(enc.c_str(), "UTF32LE");
if (handler == (iconv_t)-1) {
  std::cerr << "Couldn't create iconv handler: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
  exit(1);
}

char buf[1024];

char* inbuf = (char*)str;
size_t inbytes = sizeof(str);
char* outbuf = buf;
size_t outbytes = sizeof(buf);

while (true) {
  size_t res = iconv(handler, &inbuf, &inbytes, &outbuf, &outbytes);
  if (res != (size_t)-1) {
    break;
  }
  if (errno == EILSEQ) {
    // replace non-convertable code point with question mark and retry iconv()
    inbuf[0] = '\x3f';
    inbuf[1] = '\x00';
    inbuf[2] = '\x00';
    inbuf[3] = '\x00';
  } else {
    std::cerr << "iconv() failed: %s" << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
    exit(1);
  }
}
iconv_close(handler);

// write converted string to std::cout
std::cout.write(buf, sizeof(buf) - outbytes);
std::cout << std::endl;
// utf8: XЯ
// cp1251: XЯ?
// C: X??
```

This worked correctly in all three terminals. And now I am also not afraid that `std::cout` is used in other parts of the program. However, I find this solution not C++-way.

So, the question is: what is the correct way to print wide strings in C++? I would be fine with platform-specific solution (Linux + glibc + GCC).

Comment: You’re supposed to call `setlocale(LC_ALL,"")` to initialize the locale from the environment (not just `$LANG`).  That doesn’t fix the `wcout` issue, of course.

Comment: Thanks, by the way: I’ll add this to my list of reasons why libraries must not write to the standard streams.  (It would be easy for you to provide a `char`-based wrapper for `std::wcout` if the library relied on a stream you provided.)