# Does C++ have both byte stream classes and character stream classes?

Tags: c++, io

Java has byte stream classes (`Stream` and its subclasses), and character stream classes (`Reader` and `Writer` and their subclasses).

Does C++ have both byte stream classes and character stream classes?

Does  http://www.cs.sjsu.edu/~pearce/modules/lectures/oop/streams/streams.htm

> The standard C++ Stream Library provides input stream, output stream, and input-output stream classes. These are all character-oriented streams.

mean that C++ has only character stream classes but no byte stream classes?

Comment: What is the diefference between a byte and a character stream? I feel like in C++ you choose between them by picking an open mode (i.e. binary for byte stream, character without)

Comment: Thanks. (1) the difference between a byte and a character stream is also explained in the link. For example: Java has byte stream classes (Stream and its subclasses), and character stream classes (Reader and Writer and their subclasses). (2) Can you elaborate " in C++ you choose between them by picking an open mode (i.e. binary for byte stream, character without)"?

Comment: You just repeated the information in the question, what does the Byte stream do differently versus the character stream?

Answer (score 2):

Remember that in C++, the canonical way to represent a byte is `char`, which is an integral type. <sup>1</sup>

The C++ standard provides the [Input/Output Library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io), which provides basic input and output streams. These basic streams are templates, and the 'character' type that they work on is chosen with a template parameter. Typically, these are used in the `char` and "wide character" `wchar_t` flavours. [Other character types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Character_types) exist, like `char8_t` and `char32_t`, but their usage is a bit uncommon.

For example, file input and output in C++ can be done with a `basic_fstream` object, which takes as template parameter some type `CharT`. For convenience, we have two aliases: `fstream` is shorthand for `basic_fstream<char>`, and `wfstream` is shorthand for `basic_fstream<wchar_t>`. This pattern is also seen across other streams, like stringstreams and the standard input and output streams.

At a glance, it might seem like the "wide character" `wchar_t` would be great for working with Unicode strings. Don't be fooled. Unicode support in C++ is [seriously lacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17103925/how-well-is-unicode-supported-in-c11).

<sup>1. Admittedly, there is now a standard [`std::byte`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte), but it's usage is fairly limited. It's neither an integral type nor a character type.</sup>

**Note:** Don't mix `cout` and `wcout` in the same program. [Here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947949/mixing-cout-and-wcout-in-same-program).

Comment: If by “white space may be skipped implicitly” you’re referring to treating white space as a field separator, that’s got nothing to do with text mode versus binary mode. It’s about formatted and unformatted IO operations. Stream extractors (`<<`j and inserters (`>>`), among others, do formatted input. `read` and `write`, among others, do unformatted. Formatted IO operations skip leading white space and treat the next white space as the end of the input field.

Comment: @PeteBecker thanks for the feedback; I should have done my research more carefully