# How can I read multiple wstring lines?

Tags: c++, c++17

Is it possible to read multiple lines of international characters? I can do this with simple ascii strings:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void main ()
{
    std::string text{};
    //I cannot use std::wcin in that manner
    //std::wcout << "Enter any arbitrary text terminated by an asterisk:" << std::endl;
    //std::wstring wtext{};
    //std::getline (std::wcin, wtext, '*');THIS SPECIFIC LINE DOESN'T COMPILE
    std::cout << "Enter any arbitrary text terminated by an asterisk:" << std::endl;
    std::getline (std::cin, text, '*');
}
```

How can I achieve the same using a string type that supports international characters?

As requested, I included the line that wouldn't compile.
My doubt is: is there another way?

The error is: **no instance of overloaded function "std::getline" matches the argument list**

**Solved.** Please note the presence of an `L` prefixing `'*'` in the accepted answer. In my commented out call to `std::getline` using `wcin` and `wstring` (the one that would generate the compile error) I forgot to use a `wchar_t` literal and used a `char` literal instead. Thus the types were mismatched (`string` is composed of `char`, `wstring` of `wchar_t` - aka wide char). To represent a wide char literal, one needs to add an `L` as a prefix, i.e. `L'*'`.

Comment: *I cannot use std::wcin in that manner* Why not?

Comment: Also, C++ has terrible unicode support.  If you want to use unicode, you should get a library dedicated to it to make your life easier.

Comment: ``std::getline`` doesn't have a corresponding overload for ``wstrings`` and ``wcin``

Comment: Please create a [mcve] of the program you have problem with, and then include the errors you get from that program. If there are build errors, then copy-paste (as text) the full and complete build output into the question, and add comments on the lines where you get the errors.

Comment: [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) is a *template* using the base template [`std::basic_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string). And as such can handle any kind of character, as long as both the stream and the string uses the same character type.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is that you still use the narrow-character `'*'` instead of the wide `L'*'`? The delimiter character must be the same character type as for the stream and the string.

Comment: [Works just fine here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4086eb6dc41b5d1e).  Did you by chance forget to change `'*'` to `L'*'` in your call to `getline`?

Comment: for `std::wstring` you should use `std::wcin`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude You are right! God, that was the only thing wrong. Should I keep the question up, everyone? The issue was rather stupid, I don't know if it's worth keeping the question. I believe it is. I don't have a monopoly on stupidity; someone else could find themselves in this exact same situation someday.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here an example using `std::wstring`, `std::wcin` and `std::wcout`

By the way: [you shouldn't mix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8957069) `std::cin`, `std::cout`, `std::cerr` and `std::wcin`, `std::wcout`, `std::wcerr`. if you choose to use `std::wcin`, use only `std::wcin`, `std::wcout`, `std::wcerr`

EDIT: if you use `std::wcin` in `std::getline`, all arguments must be wide, since the `std::getline` gets only one template argument for the character type, and used it several times: for the stream, the output string, and the delimiter.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main ()
{
    std::wstring text{};
    
    std::wcout << L"Enter any arbitrary text terminated by an asterisk:" << std::endl;
    std::getline (std::wcin, text, L'*');
}
```

Comment: Yes, the lack of L in from of ``'*'`` was the problem.

Comment: @paulsm4 it's there. I put emphasis on it, maybe it was not very clear.

Comment: @SHR can you specifically mention the lack of L in front of ``*`` to make it a wide char? That was what was wrong with my code. I already know the thing about not mixing the streams, that's why those lines are commented out.