# Strange interaction between setlocale and mbstowcs

Tags: c, libc

I have a strange behaviour between setlocale and mbstowcs.

Here is a sample code :

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <clocale>

int main()
{
    std::setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");
    char * cur_ctype_locale = std::setlocale(LC_CTYPE, NULL); // line 1
    std::cout << cur_ctype_locale << std::endl; // line 2
    std::string src = "éèùç";
    size_t result_size = std::mbstowcs(NULL, &src[0], 0);
    if (result_size == (size_t)-1)
    {
        std::cout << "failed" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    std::wstring result;
    result.resize(result_size + 1);
    result_size = std::mbstowcs(&result[0], &src[0], result_size + 1);
    std::wcout << result << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When executed (on linux), the output is garbage.

When I remove the lines commented as "line 1" and "line 2" the output is correct (I see the string as defined in the sources).

As far as I read on the documentation of [setlocale](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setlocale.3.html):

```
If locale is NULL, the current locale is only queried, not modified.
```

The lines commented as "line 1" and "line 2" should only return the current locale for LC_CTYPE and not modify the locale.

Am I missing something here ?

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947949/mixing-cout-and-wcout-in-same-program answer your question? Practice making an [mcve] - you could notice, that if you comment only line 2, the output is correct. Your issue is unrelated to mbstowcs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running **Archlinux** and my the output of my `locale`:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

And running this code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <clocale>

int main()
{
    std::setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");
    char * cur_ctype_locale = std::setlocale(LC_CTYPE, NULL); // line 1
    std::cout << cur_ctype_locale << std::endl; // line 2
    std::string src = "éèùç";
    size_t result_size = std::mbstowcs(NULL, &src[0], 0);
    if (result_size == (size_t)-1)
    {
        std::cout << "failed" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    std::wstring result;
    result.resize(result_size + 1);
    result_size = std::mbstowcs(&result[0], &src[0], result_size + 1);
    if (result_size < 0) {
        std::cout << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
        printf("You error'd\n");
    } else {
        printf("You were fine...\n");
    }

    std::wcout << result << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And the output:

```
en_US.UTF-8
You were fine...
```

If you can provide some information say your output from running `locale`?

Other than that as you say by calling `setlocale` with `NULL` you're strictly querying at this point.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> std::cout <<
> std::wcout <<
> ```

It's either one or the other, you can't use both.